# Where are the results of chkdsk located in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, chkdsk

I recently ran the chkdsk in Windows 7 on my local C: drive. After chkdsk completed, the results flashed on the screen for a few seconds and then the computer booted up. I wasn't able to read the results in time. Are the results saved to a text file somewhere?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As Randolph mentions, it is in the Event Viewer. More specifically, here:

**Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application -> Wininit**

Wininit is found under the **source** column.

Comment: Thanks - it was 50 / 50 between System and Application. I've updated my answer as well.

Comment: In XP there was, since then I haven't had a use for a log, so I don't know. However, you can run CHKDSK from the command line and force it to output a text file log: CHKDSK C: /F > C:\LOG.TXT

Answer (score 19):

To add to [Paul's post](https://superuser.com/a/214235/10259):

Go to Start, then type in 'event viewer' (without the quotes) in the search bar, and then select 'Event Viewer'.

Since the Event Viewer could list tens of thousands or more events, this could make finding the 'Wininit' event (the chkdsk log) very hard.

To make this easier, when in "*Event Viewer » Windows Logs » Application*", go to "*Filter Current Log... » Filter » Event sources » check 'Wininit'*":

[image: Filter Current Log... > Filter > Event sources > check 'Wininit']

This will make the Event Viewer only show sources that are 'Wininit' (chkdsk logs only).

---

There are also chkdsk .log files, viewable in a text editor, located at `[Drive Letter]:\System Volume Information\Chkdsk`. You can only view it if Control Panel » Folder Options » 'Hidden files and folders' » 'Show hidden files, folders, and drives' is selected, 'Hide protected operating system files' is unchecked and you [took ownership](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/) of that folder.

Comment: Way better detail than the accepted answer, but my +1 is really for the `Chkdsk*.log`. I used my old Windows to fix my USB drive while away - but am very glad to access the log as normal UTF-16 under Linux, without having to suffer with my old boot drive and Windows itself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip re. filtering the event log.

Comment: ... and yes, *WAY* better than the accepted answer - much more informative *and* detailed.  Thank you for that, as well !!

Answer (score 11):

Here's an alternative way to view the results (found [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/96938-check-disk-chkdsk-read-event-viewer-log.html)):

1. Press the Windows + R keys to open the Run dialog, type powershell.exe, and press Enter.
2. In PowerShell, copy and paste the command below, and press Enter. (see screenshot below)
   NOTE: To paste the copied command into PowerShell, you will just need to right click in PowerShell.
3. Enter the command

   ```
   get-winevent -FilterHashTable @{logname="Application"; id="1001"}| ?{$_.providername –match "wininit"} | fl timecreated, message | out-file Desktop\CHKDSKResults.txt
   ```
4. You will now have a CHKDSKResults.txt file created on your desktop that is the log file of your chkdsk scan results from Event Viewer.

Comment: Very nice. Consistent across Windows versions and so much simpler than navigating the new event viewer.

Comment: I like it. Anything is better than dealing with EventViewer.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for this nice solution it help a lot here and this what exactly i'm looking for [How can I get the results of a CHKDSK that ran on boot ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38504689/how-can-i-get-the-results-of-a-chkdsk-that-ran-on-boot)

Comment: FYI: Since I wanted to get a log created not at the boot time, I had to use different filters: `get-winevent -FilterHashTable @{logname="Application"; id="26214"}| ?{$_.providername –match "
Chkdsk"} | fl timecreated, message | out-file CHKDSKResults.txt`. I also noticed that sometimes ID=26212 is used as well.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the chkdsk scan was not done at boot time. I ran chkdsk on an external drive through the Windows Explorer UI, tried this command but got an empty CHKDSKResults.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Event Viewer, under <strike>`System`</strike> `Application`, but in some cases it won't show at all.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see anything at all about chkdsk. Is it saved to a file somewhere or can you run it so that the results are saved to a specific file?

Comment: No, there is no file, check Paul's answer for details about how to localize it.