# How to see check disk report on Drive C

Tags: windows, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are the results of chkdsk located in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/214209/where-are-the-results-of-chkdsk-located-in-windows-7)

As you know when check drive C with chkdsk it schedules it for pre-boot run. But when windows comes up it does not show result dialogbox as shown on other drives. I want to check if drive C has bad sectors or not just in simple words.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the chkdsk results with Event Viewer with Source Winnit in the Application logs.
[This article](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/96938-check-disk-chkdsk-read-event-viewer-log.html) on Sevenforums describes the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find it through the Event Viewer.
If not, then you must execute the command through WinPE or something similar.
Then if you want to save it you can pipe the output to a file.