# List of damaged files from chkdsk process

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, chkdsk

I chkdsk'ed my external HDD and found that some files have been damaged.

Can I get the full list of deleted files from this chkdsk process?
Command prompt window shows part of the file list but even I scroll up to the top, I can't see the entire file list.

This is NOT the duplicate of 
[Where are the results of chkdsk located in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/214209/where-are-the-results-of-chkdsk-located-in-windows-7)
The answer of the above question does not tell me where is "the list of files"

Comment: You must have missed the bit of the dup answer that says "There are also chkdsk .log files, viewable in a text editor, located at [Drive Letter]:\System Volume Information\Chkdsk. You can only view it if Control Panel » Folder Options » 'Hidden files and folders' » 'Show hidden files, folders, and drives' is selected, 'Hide protected operating system files' is unchecked and you took ownership of that folder."

Comment: Rather than ask a new question, you should edit your first question [List of deleted files from chkdsk process](http://superuser.com/q/1020474) if you feel that the duplicate doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check it in windows event logs ...

Instructions [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/96938-check-disk-chkdsk-read-event-viewer-log.html).

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.